# Increase search field maxlength?

Tags: 7

Currently the search field has a maxlength of 128, I am wondering if there is any way to increase it too maybe 255?

Comment: Have you tried using `hook_form_alter` and changing the `#size` property of the textfield? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#size

Comment: (`#maxlength`, not `#size`)

Comment: From what I can tell, only the Search Field in the Search *Block* has a limit of 128 characters. The field in the form at the top of the search results page has a limit of 255 already. Interesting. That makes me think that this would be as simple as using `hook_form_alter()` to increase `#maxlength` as @Clive and @rwaery have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it's not pretty. Drupal really doesn't want you to change field definitions after they've been created.

The correct way would be to create a new field definition and migrate values from the old field into the new one.

The quick and dirty way would be to manually change the field definition in the database directly.

The quick and dirty way that is deployable via code is to do a two-step process:

1. Export the field (such as with Features) and alter the `#maxlength` setting in the code.
2. TEMPORARILY hack core by commenting out the code in `hook_field_update_forbid()` in field.api.php.
3. Deploy a tag containing 1 and 2. Run updates.
4. UNCOMMENT `hook_field_update_forbid` and deploy that tag so further changes are not allowed and core is put back in its natural state.

This is terrible but I have done it and it works.